# What is the difference between Toast and Notification on Android?

Tags: android, notifications, toast

Can someone clearly explain the difference between a "Toast" and a "Notification" on the Android platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toast doesn't give any kind of alert, and that is not clickable it is used to show message to end user.
While in notification user gets alert and from that notification they are directly go to the application

Answer (score 2):

[A toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) is a small display on the bottom of the screen.

[A notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) is displayed in the top menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

1. The toast class is used to display alerts to the user; it disappears
   after a few seconds. 
   The NotificationManager class is used to
   display notifications on the device's status bar.
2. Toast with LENTH_LONG will display for 3.5 seconds.
   The alert displayed by the NotificationManager class is persistent and can only be dismissed by the user when selected.
3. We can set Gravity to Top, Bottom or Center in Toast.
   Notification displays only at status bar.